# How to set default filters in Material-UI Data-Grid/XGrid component when using paginationMode="server"

Tags: material-ui

When I use:

```
filterModel={{
              items: [
                  { columnField: 'name', operatorValue: 'contains', value: 'xxx' },
              ]
          }}
```

when using server side pagination with:

```
<XGrid
  paginationMode="server"
  onFilterModelChange={onFilterChange}
  ...
/>

    const onFilterChange = useCallback(params => {
        setFilterModel(params.filterModel)
    }, [])
```

the page gets stuck in an infinite loop.

Is there a way to set default filters when using server side pagination mode?